# Why prefix kubernetes manifest files with numbers?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy Node.js code to a Kubernetes cluster, and I'm seeing that in my reference (provided by the maintainer of the cluster) that the `yaml` files are all prefixed by numbers:

```
00-service.yaml
10-deployment.yaml
etc.
```

I don't think that this file format is specified by `kubectl`, but I found another example of it online: https://imti.co/kibana-kubernetes/ (but the numbering scheme isn't the same).

Is this a Kubernetes thing? A file naming convention? Is it to keep files ordered in a folder?

Comment: How are you deploying these specs to the cluster?  Although you're correct that the name of the files doesn't mean anything, they could be helpful to tell a non-standard deployment tool what order the specs should be applied in.  For example, it may be helpful to upload the configuration for deployment's pods before uploading the deployment.

Comment: The deployment is managed by GitLab, configured in `.gitlab-ci.yml`. In the deploy stage the manifest files are applied using kubectl in a specified order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to handle the resource creation order. There's an opened issue in kubernetes:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/16448#issue-113878195

tl;dr `kubectl apply -f k8s/*` should handle the order but it does not.

However, except the namespace, I cannot imagine where the order will matter. Every relation except namespace is handled by label selectors, so it fixes itself once all resources are deployed. You can just do 00-namespace.yaml and everything else without prefixes. Or just skip prefixes at all unless you really hit the issue (I never faced it).

Comment: Does this pattern still matter if you're using [Kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/) to define the ordering of the resources? From this issue it looks like it doesn't: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/65

Answer (score 2):

When you execute `kubectl apply *` the files are executed alphabetically. Prefixing files with a rising number allows you to control the order of the executed files. But in nearly all cases the order shouldn't matter.

Comment: Just wanna add that there can be dependencies between manifests. For example, namespace should be created first, then you need to provide configmaps, secrets, otherwise deployments won't start and so on...

Comment: We aren't using apply *. We're doing each explicitly. Thank you though - I didn't know that was an option

Comment: @VasilyAngapov Thats true I'll adjust my answer to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Sequence helps in readability, user friendly and not the least maintainability. Looking at the resources one can conclude in which order the deployment needs to be performed. For example, deployment using configMap object would fail if the deployment is done before configMap is created.